# Springboot API, receive file

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, file-upload

I'm trying to make simple Springbot API that will be receive file from frontend. All tutorials that I found is complex and is too much for me. For educational purpose I just wanna to get file and print name of file.

Code that I tried:

```
@PostMapping(path="/postFile")
public void postFile(@RequestBody MultipartFile file){
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

Code return that variable file is null, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Code from my frontend

```
function clickHandler(){
    
     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('File',selectedFile);

     fetch("https://localhost:8443/postFile", {
         method: 'POST',
         body:  formData
     })
}
```

Comment: `formData.append('File',selectedFile);` change this to `formData.append('file',selectedFile);` Key `file` should be lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

Use @RequestParam("File") instead of @RequestBody. As you are sending a form where your file is bounded to field 'File'.